# Корректное использование сочетаний слов

Tags: грамотная-речь

В фразе "информационная система предприятия ООО "Квант" не дублируют ли друг друга слова "предприятие" и "ООО"?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, здесь не дублируют.
*ИС предприятия* - сложившийся термин. Наряду, скажем, с *ИС бухгалтерии*, *ИС управления производством* и т.д. Даже сокращение иногда используется - ИСП.
Т.е. в первом приближении будет верно сказать, что в данном случае "предприятие" относится к ИС, а ООО - к названию "Квант".

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то, ООО - это "общество с ограниченной ответственностью", то есть тавтологии тут нет. Но все же подряд идут слова со схожими понятиями, поэтому, мне кажется, что слово "предприятие" вполне можно опустить.

Answer (score 0):

Аббревиатуру ИСП лучше не использовать. ИСП - Интернет Сервис Провайдер.